# Eclipse Plugins disappeared

Tags: eclipse, plugins, adt

After a ubuntu update all my eclipse plugin have disappeared, inclcuding ADT Plugin, Database Plugin, and PHP Plugin. If I install "new" software, eclipse gives my the error "Duplicated Location". Great

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Did the Eclipse version get updated?  Either way, from my experience the best option is to do a fresh install of Eclipse to make sure there's no cruft sitting around from previous installations (better to eliminate the possibility now then have some bug down the road that may be attributed to a code issue).

Comment: I don't trust Eclipse installs from distros. The package managers in distros often don't know how to handle Eclipse, especially for updates.

Comment: And the distro package buys you nothing with Eclipse since it's pretty self-contained.